# Checagem de null retorna erro de referência

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

**Model**

```
public class Transacao
{
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult ManterTransacao(int idTransacao = 0)
{
    (...)

    Transacao transacao = null;

    if (idTransacao > 0)
    {
        transacao = new DaoTransacao().DadosTransacao(idTransacao);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model Web.Models.Transacao

(...)

if (Model != null)
{
    <input type="hidden" name="idTransacao" value="@Model.ID" />
}
```

Meu `controller` serve para incluir **E** atualizar dados através da mesma view. Se for uma atualização de dados, o `input="hidden"` de nome `idTransacao` é incluído na página. Essa inserção ocorre quando `Model` não for nulo, como mostrado na controller (a referência do objeto é criada apenas se o valor do parâmetro `idTransacao` for fornecido e for maior que 0).

No entanto, essa validação falha:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Já que o objeto passado como modelo à view é nulo, onde está o erro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tiago, eu trocaria este código:

```
if (Model.ID > 0) // Se for uma referência vazia, o valor será 0
{
    <input type="hidden" name="idTransacao" value="@Model.ID" />
}
```

Por este:

```
@Html.Hidden("idTransacao", Model.ID)
```

Outra coisa que seria performático colocar seria na `Action` chamadora, a instanciação da sua `Transacao`:

```
public ActionResult EditarTransacao(int idTransacao = 0)
{
    (...)

    return View(transacao ?? new Transacao());
}
```

Comment: Grande Cigano! Como sempre, irrepreensível nas colocações.

Answer (score 2):

O erro está na forma como está ocorrendo a instanciação do modelo. Em nosso controller, devemos criar uma referência vazia na variável `transacao`:

```
var transacao = new Transacao();
```

E, na validação da view, verificar se o ID é maior que zero (já que se trata de uma `IDENTITY`:

```
if (Model.ID > 0) // Se for uma referência vazia, o valor será 0
{
    <input type="hidden" name="idTransacao" value="@Model.ID" />
}
```

Simplesmente atribuir `null` a `transacao` não funciona, porque a view espera um objeto do tipo `Transacao`.